# XRDP Custom Resolution (Fedora 19)

Tags: fedora, display-settings, i3

How can I configure a custom display resultion for xrdp sessions? 
I want the session to use all the display size, minus few lines for the original decorations. that will be around 1920x1050, a resultion that isn't available in xrandr.

I'm using i3 as wm, so there is no GUI or DE configuration tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, following schaiba's link to the bug report, I have created .sh script with the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --newmode "1920x1040_60.00"  165.50  1920 2040 2240 2560  1040 1043 1053 1079 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VNC-0 "1920x1040_60.00"
xrandr -s 1920x1040
```

after chmod +x the file and putting it in my ~/.vnc folder it gets executed when I login with xrdp.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have rep to upvote or comment on schaiba's answer, but in Fedora 19, disabling xrandr is a workaround to force the resolution.

```
sudo yum install -y dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

browse to org -> gnome -> settings-daemon -> plugins > xrandr
and uncheck Active

I can now connect using rdesktop and force a resolution.

```
rdesktop -g 800x600 192.168.1.xxx
```

Comment: I don't have the rep to vote him either, otherwise I would since it did help like I said in my comment. However, Gnome isn't synonimous with fedora, and I sont have Gnome installed on my system so the bug part wasn't my issue. I still don't know where or how to set the xrandr settings so that they will affect only xrdep sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the docs I can't really see such option for xrdp's command line or xrdp.ini, but what I do see is Fedora bug #973486, which might help you. Looks like a bug in gnome-settings-daemon and the suggested workaround is disabling the xrandr plugin in g-s-d.

Comment: I guess I should have mentionend it, I'm using i3 and It's a minimal installation. I don't have gnome on the system. I probably can solve the issue by installing xfce and setting it from there, but that defeats the target of keeping minimal installtion.

Comment: Okay, that did help me to solve the problem. added the lines menitioned in the article to shell script and added that script to the start of my .i3/config file. I still wish I knew how to run the script only on xrdp sessions.